# logical_and with nested boolean arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have one (very long) boolean array `a` with `k` `True` entries, and one boolean array `b` of length `k`. I would like to get a boolean array `c` that is `True` if and only if `a` "and" `b` are `True`:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.array([False, False, True, False, True, False])
b = numpy.array([True, False])

assert numpy.sum(a) == len(b)  # guaranteed

c = numpy.zeros(len(a), dtype=bool)
idx_b = 0
for k in range(len(a)):
    if a[k]:
        if b[idx_b]:
            c[k] = True
        idx_b += 1

print(c)
```

```
[False False  True False False False]
```

This here uses a loop, but I'm thinking there must a faster way with boolean indexing, but I can't quite get to it.

Any hints?

Comment: So out of bounds is treated as False?

Comment: out-of-bounds how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply mask input array with itself (*self-masking?)* and assign -

```
a[a] = b
```

If you need output in a new array, copy the input array and perform masking on the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the assertion holds true, you can use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([False, False, True, False, True, False])
b = np.array([True, False])

assert np.sum(a) == len(b)

c = np.copy(a)
idx = np.flatnonzero(c) 
c[idx] = b

print(c)
```

Out:

```
[False, False,  True, False, False, False]
```